# Как отключить android.permission.SEND_SMS?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-permissions

Google Play удалил приложение в связи с новой политикой использования разрешений.
Я не использую `android.permission.SEND_SMS`, перерыл весь код, нигде ничего не запрашиваю, так же просмотрел библиотеки там тоже ничего нет. При загрузке новой версии в стор, отображается сообщение о том что ранее было обозначено разрешение, но ранее так же не использовал SEND_SMS. Я использую Firebase Auth Phone Number, может ли он запрашивать это разрешение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю поможет ли Вам это сейчас, но чтобы узнать что откуда берётся нужно смотреть манифест в режиме [Merged Manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Посмотрите ответы тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55508535/3212712

Comment: Проблема была в том, что в Play Console версия с SEND_SMS была опубликована в альфа тестировании, просто обновил версию и все стало нормально.

Comment: @Colibri, думаю, это можно в ответ написать)